# JNI problem on OSX

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, awt, jai

I'm running into problems using AWT classes on OSX (10.5.8) with Java 6 (1.6.0_17 JVM: 14.3-b01-101).
Trying to load java.awt.Dimension the code just freezes, this happens in Eclipse or from the command line. Anyone experiencing same problems ?
The class is used by JAI in the following code:

```
public static byte[] resizeAsJPG(byte[] imageContent, double scale, float outputQuality) throws IllegalArgumentException,
  ImageOperationException {
if (scale <= 0) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("scale must be a positive number");
}
if (outputQuality <= 0 || outputQuality > 1.0F) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("outputQuality must be between 0 and 1");
}
try {
  // Fetch input image to seekable stream
  RenderedOp originalImage = getRenderedOp(imageContent);
  ((OpImage) originalImage.getRendering()).setTileCache(null);

  // Set scale parameters
  ParameterBlock saclingParams = new ParameterBlock();
  saclingParams.addSource(originalImage); // The source image
  saclingParams.add(scale); // The xScale
  saclingParams.add(scale); // The yScale
  saclingParams.add(0.0); // The x translation
  saclingParams.add(0.0); // The y translation

  // RenderingHints renderingHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
  Map<RenderingHints.Key, Object> renderingHints = new HashMap<RenderingHints.Key, Object>();
  renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
  renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
  renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
  renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

  // Scale using sub-sampling average which provides much better quality than bicubic interpolation
  RenderedOp scaledImage = JAI.create("SubsampleAverage", saclingParams, new RenderingHints(renderingHints));

  // Encode scaled image as JPEG
  JPEGEncodeParam encodeParam = new JPEGEncodeParam();
  encodeParam.setQuality(outputQuality);

  // Since we scale height and width (don't take into account the quality)
  int outputSizeEstimate = (int) (imageContent.length * scale * scale);
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(outputSizeEstimate);
  ImageEncoder encoder = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("JPEG", outputStream, encodeParam);
  encoder.encode(scaledImage);
  return outputStream.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new ImageOperationException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Cocoa version of Eclipse? (vs Carbon) If so, that may be the cause. See the discussion on this thread: [Java getDefaultToolKit() hangs Mac OS X 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201085/java-getdefaulttoolkit-hangs-mac-os-x-10-5)

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the "-Djava.awt.headless=true" flag from the command line, which will allow AWT classes to run without having to initialize a GUI.